# Is there a workaround/fix to these Google Maps v2 StackOverflowError crashes?

Tags: android, google-maps

Seeing multiple crashes in my production app related to Google Maps v2, hundreds per day.

I can repro the issue even on Lyft, Yelp, Ritual apps.

**Repro Steps**

1. Add com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps 11.8.0 or above (also
   crashes on 15.0.0) to app
2. Get Google Play Services 12.6.85 (040400-197041431)
3. Add SupportMapFragment
4. Open app, center map on "Mission District" in San Francisco, CA, USA
5. Try zooming in and out very fast, or scrolling up and down but always keeping Missin District in the center

**Expected**

1. No Crash

**Actual**

1. Crash

As an aggregate, the crashes hit multiple OS's: 5, 6, 7, 8. Individually, the crashes I've looked at target 1-2 OS's max, e.g. 5+6, 7, 7+8.

The stack traces all seem to involve `com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.*` packages.

This is the closest issue I saw on [AOSP Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829548). Check out the Duplicates on that issue for similar issues with different stacktraces.

Here are snippets of some of the stacktraces I see (there are a LOT more):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1038KB
       at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:393)
       at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:348)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):7)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):193)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1037KB
      at java.util.HashMap.createEntry(HashMap.java:826)
      at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:813)
      at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:436)
      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):17)
      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):193)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:556)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):7)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):193)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1037KB
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:191)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.i.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):9)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):159)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):161)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1037KB
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):5)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):33)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1037KB
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.i.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):9)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):159)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1037KB
      at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:630)
      at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):17)
      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):193)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1037KB
     at java.util.HashMap.remove(HashMap.java:798)
     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):29)
     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):37)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1036KB
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:300)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685009@12.6.85 (020308-197041431):20)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.cache.s.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685009@12.6.85 (020308-197041431):8)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1038KB
       at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:364)
       at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:171)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.i.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):9)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):159)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After trying multiple things, the following is a workaround that worked for me, if you don't require indoor mapping.

```
// Kotlin
googleMap.isIndoorEnabled = false

// Java
googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
```

All the crashes I was seeing were related to the indoor package, so this makes some sense. Hopefully, a fix is released soon. Will post if the [issue on AOSP tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829548) is solved.

#### Update

Good news. Google marked the bug as Fixed on October 20, 2018. Also it was mentioned in release notes of latest Maps Android SDK in Google Play Services

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/releases#october_18_2018

Comment: Kotlin? In Java I added `mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);` I haven't verified if this works yet, because I cannot reproduce the error myself and I only have one or two crashes reported in Crashlytics.

Comment: @swooby correct, updated the answer with Kotlin + Java code

Comment: This is also the correct answer [for now] per https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829548#comment4

Comment: We still are experiencing this issue (with the workaround above)

Comment: @DimaNemets can you post your stack trace in another question and link it here? As Google mentioned in the AOSP tracker, the workaround I mention will solve these particular categories of issues.

Comment: @vman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881803/google-maps-stackoverflowerror-crashes