# Google Maps StackOverflowError crashes

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

Getting the following error even after applying the workaround described here: [Is there a workaround/fix to these Google Maps v2 StackOverflowError crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691006/is-there-a-workaround-fix-to-these-google-maps-v2-stackoverflowerror-crashes/50691007?noredirect=1#comment88729170_50691007)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1036KB
   at java.util.HashMap.remove(HashMap.java:616)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):29)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):37)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):9)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):193)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):100)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):88)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):164)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):292)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):200)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):198)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):100)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):88)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):164)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):292)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):200)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):198)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):100)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):88)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):164)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):292)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):200)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):198)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):100)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):88)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):164)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):292)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):200)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):198)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):100)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):88)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):164)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):292)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):200)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):198)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):100)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):88)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):164)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):292)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):200)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):198)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):100)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):88)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):164)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):292)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):200)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):198)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):100)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):88)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):164)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):292)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):200)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):198)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):100)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):88)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):164)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):292)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):200)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):198)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):100)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):88)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):164)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):292)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):200)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):198)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):100)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):88)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):164)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):292)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.g(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):169)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.indoor.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):156)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bd.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):37)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):353)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bb.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685013@12.6.85 (020700-197041431):230)
```

The crash happens even after applying the workaround: `googleMap.isIndoorEnabled = false` which was added following information in [AOSP issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829548#comment4) and the mentioned [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691006/is-there-a-workaround-fix-to-these-google-maps-v2-stackoverflowerror-crashes/50691007?noredirect=1#comment88729170_50691007)

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370546/banned-from-reviewing-through-a-really-strange-question)

Comment: Good news. Google marked the bug as Fixed on October 20, 2018. Also it was mentioned in release notes of latest Maps Android SDK in Google Play Services 

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/releases#october_18_2018